# It looks when i am redirecting to the page the product is not loaded and i get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class EditProductComponent implements OnInit {
  product: IProduct;
  uploader: FileUploader;
  hasBaseDropZoneOver = false;
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  currentMain!: Photo;
  response!:string;
  photos: PhotoPicture[] = [];
  productForm:FormGroup;

  constructor(private shopService: ShopService, private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private bcService: BreadcrumbService,private fb: FormBuilder,
    private http:HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createAddProductForm();
    this.loadProduct();
  }

  loadProduct() {
    console.log(+this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!);
    this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!).subscribe(product => {
      console.log(product);
      this.product = product;
      this.photos = product.pictures;
      console.log(this.photos);
      this.bcService.set('@productDetails', product.name)

      this.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: this.baseUrl + 'photos/'+product.id  + '/photos',
        authToken: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        isHTML5: true,
        allowedFileType: ['image'],
        removeAfterUpload: true,
        autoUpload: false,
        maxFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 
      });
      console.log(this.productForm);
      if(product)
      {
        this.productForm.setValue({name: product.name, 
          description: product.description,
          id:product.id
        ,price: product.price, 
        quantity:product.quantity, 
        size:product.productSize  ,productSizeId: this.sizes.find(p => p.name == product.productSize)!.id  
        ,color: product.productColor, productColorId: this.colors.find(p => p.name == product.productColor)!.id 
       ,gender : product.productGender, productGenderId: this.genders.find(p => p.name == product.productGender)!.id,
         fit: product.productFit, productfitId:this.fits.find(p => p.name == product.productFit)!.id,
        type: product.productType, producttypeId: this.types.find(p => p.name == product.productType)!.id,
        brand:product.productBrand, productbrandId: this.brands.find(p => p.name == product.productBrand)!.id});
      }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }



  }

}
```

So here i am getting my product from shopService that makes a request to the API to get the product that correspond with the id that is given in the link..i have cheked and when i enter the page the product has the good data...for example i have an array where i store my photos and they are displayed as it should be but when i am trying to initialise my form values from the product i get => ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
When i refresh the page all seems to work my form is getting the data as it should but when i enter the page for the first time the form is not getting any values

Comment: you have product.id inside FileUploader. But you check if a product exists later in code. So you can move the code for the FileUploader inside the if(product) and you should not get the error

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at Object.next (edit-product.component.ts:103:103)
    at EditProductComponent.loadProduct (edit-product.component.ts:78:83) The error comes like this. the second is pointing to this: this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!).subscribe(product => {   AND for the first to this:         size:product.productSize  ,productSizeId: this.sizes.find(p => p.name == product.productSize)!.id